# A non-empty set has no accumulation points iff all points are isolated

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Statement: A non-empty set has no accumulation points iff all points are isolated.

So far I have said to Let $S= \{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$, such that $S$ has no accumulation points.
Then $\exists$ $\epsilon<|x-x_i|$ which by this I mean that since $S$ is finite, there will always be some $\epsilon$*-neighborhood* around an arbitrary $x\in S$ where $\epsilon <$ the smallest distance between $2$ points in $S$ which should show that all points are isolated.

If that portion is correct, how do I go about proving the other direction?

From my book, the definition of an isolated point just says "a point $x$ is an isolated point of $S$ if $x\in S$ and $x$ is not an accumulation point of $S$"

Is the answer then simply to say since all points are isolated, they are not accumulation points and therefore $S$ has no accumulation points?

Comment: The item billed as a "statement" does not include (or imply) that the set $S$ is finite. Is finiteness of $S$ an unstated hypothesis?

Comment: No the statement didn't include anything about S being finite, am I wrong to assume that the set can be finite in this case? @leslietownes

Comment: Wouldn't the set $S = \{ 1/n \mid n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 1}\}$ qualify as a counterexample? It accumulates at $0$ but is a set of entirely isolated points.

Comment: Where finiteness is concerned it is not strictly necessary though, it ultimately depends on the topology you're dealing with. For instance, $S = \mathbb{Z}$ is infinite and meets the premise, as would any discrete metric space of arbitrary size.

Comment: I had considered that already but assumed it was incorrect as 0 is not included in S, or does that not matter for this? @EeveeTrainer

Comment: Usually, accumulation points of a set do not need to belong to the set. "A point $x$ is an accumulation point of a set $S$ if every open neighborhood of $x$ contains a point in $S$ not equal to $x$" is a common definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly in the statement given it is simply said "A non-empty set", therefore the set can be infinite or finite as well. So if you are indexing the elements of set up to $n$ elements it implies that set is finite. Then you may have to deal with infinite case separately.

Consider the set $S = \{\frac{1}{n}: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. Each point in the set is an isolated point(meaning you can find a neighborhood around the point $x$ - isolated point, such that the neighborhood contains only $x$).

Reason: For every $x = 1/n \in S$, take $\epsilon < \frac{1}{n+1}$ then the open ball centered at $x$ with radius of $\epsilon$ - $B_{\epsilon} (x) \, \cap S = \{x\}$.

But $0$ is an accumulation point of the set $S$. To see this take any $\epsilon > 0, \exists \, n $ such that $1/n < \epsilon$ (By Archimedean property).

The above example illustrates that you can have a set $S$ where all of its points are isolated but has an accumulation point.

Comment: More extreme example: Any Cantor set (nonempty perfect subset of the reals) is equal to the set of accumulation points of the collection of midpoints of its bounded complementary open intervals, and each of these midpoints is isolated from any of the other midpoints (indeed, each is also isolated from any of the points in the Cantor set). Thus, the collection of accumulation points of an isolated set (note: isolated sets are always countable) can have cardinality continuum, and even have positive Lebesgue measure.